# Dynamicish Inheritance

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript I am trying out an exercise wherein I have some object nested inside some object and I am using inheritance to combine them all together. Simply put, the main goal is to be able to execute this line of code:

```
Vehicle1 = new Vehicle("Car");
Print(Vehicle.Car("Toyota").Toyota("Red").printEverythingInherited()); //should print Car, Toyota, Red

Vehicle2 = new Vehicle("Car");
Print(Vehicle.Car("Honda").Toyota("Blue").printEverythingInherited()); //should print Car, Honda, Blue
```

I am unsure if this type of code is possible to execute, I'm faily new to JavaScript. Below is my implementation and I would like some feedback on how to move forward.

Also, I would like to point out that I want to avoid creating

```
Car = new Toyota("Blue")
```

I need to create it as:

```
Car = Vehicle("Car").Car("Toyota").Toyota("Blue")
```

```js
function Vehicle(type) {
  this.Vehicle = type
}

Vehicle.prototype.Car = Car

function Car(brand) {
  //Vehicle.call(this, "g")
  this.brand = brand
}

Car.prototype.Toyota = Toyota
Car.prototype.Honda = Honda

function Honda(color) {
  this.color = color

  function printEverythingInherited() {
    print(this.Vehicle + this.brand + this.color) should print Car, Honda, Red
  }
}

function Toyota(color) {
  this.color = color
  this.getPriviledgedFunctionColor = function() {
    Log.Message("Toyota() " + this.color)
  }
}


Vehicle = new Vehicle("Car");
Print(Vehicle.Car("Toyota").Toyota("Red").printEverythingInherited());
```

Comment: Why does your Honda have a `.Toyota` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is not inheritance, but the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Which you might be able to combine with the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Pattern) if you really need different classes.

```
function Factory(props, vals) {
    if (!vals) vals = [];
    this.create = function() {
        return vals.reduce(function(instance, val, i) {
            instance[props[i]] = val;
            return instance;
        }, {});
    };
    props.forEach(function(prop, i) {
        this[prop] = function(val) {
            var nvals = vals.slice();
            nvals[i] = val;
            return new Factory(props, nvals);
        };
    }, this);
}
var Vehicle = new Factory(["type", "brand", "color"]);
var Car = Vehicle.type("car");

var car1 = Car.brand("toyota").color("red").create();
var car2 = Car.brand("honda").color("blue").create();
```